# How to play audio in iOS with UI of music player?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, audio

I am trying to play audio in iOS using AVPlayer but i am not able to see any Deafault UI fro playing the audio. Here is my code

```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"];

   playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];

    player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

   player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];

   [player play];
```

Audio os played but not any audio player UI is diplayed as in case of `MPMoviePlayerController` UI is shown while playing the video.Please tell me the solution here?

Comment: You have to create your own UI. iOS does not provide any native UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS is not providing any native kind of the UI for Playing Audio for that.you create own UI and that manage by the developer thru `AVAudioPlayer` class.

Here is tutorial for the custom [Playing Audio with AVAudioPlayer](http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2012/10/01/tutorial-playing-audio-with-avaudioplayer/)